# ElasticSearch Failing to Sort Nested Object in order

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.5.2 Given the mapping and query, the document order is not effected by changing 'desc' to 'asc' and vice versa.  Not seeing any errors, just `sort: [Infinity]` in the results.

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "metrics": {
          "type": "nested",
          "dynamic": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "metrics.http.test.value": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Document structure:

```
{
  "tags": ["My Tag"],
  "metrics": {
    "http.test": {
      "updated_at": "2018-12-08T23:22:07.056Z",
      "value": 0.034
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing the mapping to this:

```
"metrics": {
  "dynamic": true,
  "properties": {}
}
```

Fixed it and allowed sorting to happen in the correct order.

Comment: The reason this worked is because `metrics` is now of `object` type rather than `nested`.

Answer (score 3):

When sorting by nested field it is necessary to tell the path of nested field using `nested` param.
One thing more you were missing in the query is the field on which to sort. Assuming you want to sort on `updated_at` the query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "metrics.http.test.updated_at": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "metrics"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One more thing that you should keep in mind while sorting using nested field is about `filter` clause in sort. Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting).

Comment: The nested path thing wasn't required, that's for pre 6.5 I believe.  Got it to work though, will mark yours up and add the solution, looks like I pasted the query a bit long.

Comment: Nested path will be required if the field is of nested doc.